# redirecting an output of command to /proc

Tags: c, linux

I have created a kernel module to have a proc file into which I can read and write data. After using `insmod mymodule.ko`, I am able to write simple text into my proc file as:

```
echo "Hello world" > /proc/myprocfile
```

I am also able to read data from my proc file properly using:

```
cat /proc/myprocfile
```

My question is if I want to write the contents of a command say, `ls /proc` rather than simply echoing a message, then how to send the output of such command to `myprocfile`.

Comment: `ls /proc > /proc/myprocfile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ls /proc > /proc/myprocfile
```

Since this seems to be what you were looking for, [here is the wikipedia page on IO redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29) which gives more examples and explains some of the other IO redirection operations.